# How can I move images around in html or CSS?

Tags: html, css

As the title says I'd like to move around the images which are in the html file. I tried some options both in html and CSS to no avail. When I try to change the properties of a picture in CSS so I can lower it further down, nothing happens.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
      <style>
         img {
            float: right;
         }
         r1 {
            float:  center;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body background="background.jpg">

    <img class="manonmoon" src="C:\Users\raven\Desktop\Promo Page Rocketman (1)\Priloga\planet-violet-astronout.png" height="550"/>

      <img class="r1" src="C:\Users\raven\Desktop\Promo Page Rocketman (1)\Priloga\r1.png" height="110"/>

      <img class="r2" src="C:\Users\raven\Desktop\Promo Page Rocketman (1)\Priloga\r2.png" height="110"/>

      <img class="r3" src="C:\Users\raven\Desktop\Promo Page Rocketman (1)\Priloga\r3.png" height="110"/>

   </body>

</html>
```

and also for CSS:

```
.r2{

position:  relative;
left: 20px;

}
```

Comment: `position: relative` won't give you what you want. You can try `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`.

Comment: You can position element in css with flexbox or grid (not only images, any elements)

Comment: There is no such thing as float: center. As @cloned has suggested look into flex and grid (unless you want text to float around the images in which case float is still useful). Also be aware of your CSS syntax. There needs to be a dot (.) before the r1 selector and be aware of how CSS calculates the priorities of the selectors it's been given. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 1):

add css class symbol when calling the ri class name

wrong `r1`

correct `.r1`

Answer (score 0):

If it's for a site that will be used on a lot of diffent devices with different screensizes then you'll probably want to use a flexbox or grid with CSS. But that's kinda hard to wrap your head around in the beginning.

If it's a page that will only be used by you on a device with a screenresolution that you already know, then it might be easier to just use `position: absolute;` and play with the `top:...;` and `left:...;` values.

```css
body {
  background-image: url('background.jpg');
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 1px black; /*Remove this, just for visualation without img sources*/
}

.manonmoon {
  width: 300px; /*Remove this or replace with auto*/
  height: 550px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.r1, .r2, .r3 {
  width: 90px; /*Remove this or replace with auto*/
  height: 110px;
}

.r1 {
  top: 560px;
  left: 0px;
}

.r2 {
  top: 560px;
  left: 105px;
}

.r3 {
  top: 560px;
  left: 210px;
}
```

```html
<img class="manonmoon" src=".." alt="...">
<img class="r1" src="..." alt="...">
<img class="r2" src="..." alt="...">
<img class="r3" src="..." alt="...">
```